# Importing of pictures by referencing a cell

Tags: excel, ms-word, powerpoint, vba

In my line of work, I have to take photos and place them in a specified folder on the network. Then, I will have to insert those photos into MS Word/Powerpoint and print them.

I am intending to use Excel to aid in this matter as I'm more familliar with Excel vba. My idea is to key in a unique ID into a cell. Using that, I am hoping to find a way to see if there is any code that can make Excel reference that ID against the folders on the network drive. If possible, I can then write a code to import the pictures into the document.

Is the referencing step possible in Excel?

Comment: Yes, but VBA is VBA.  The same VBA runs behind *Powerpoint*, *Word*, *Access*, or any other *MS Office* program.  You can always get to the VBA backend by hitting alt-F11.  If the only reason you are using *Excel* is as a way to input a photo's ID, find the picture, and stick it onto a *Powerpoint* slide, it is much simpler to just write that code straight in *Powerpoint*.  Referencing *Powerpoint* from *Excel* is one of those really cool things the *MS Office* does well, but why do it when *Excel* really doesn't have anything to do with it?  Just do it in *Powerpoint*.

Comment: Seems that you want to use Excel to keep track of the photos (using a unique key/ID), and yes you can use Excel as your library/dictionary of unique IDs.  Then if you set it up correctly, you can run VBA in PPT to Excel to import the pictures.  If you write some code and need help, come back and post a code question.

Comment: O that's fantastic. I shall try to explore PPT VBA. Thanks guys!